# Method for finding permutation of n elements if you have all permutations of (n-1) elements

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

In the "The Art of Computer Programming Volume 1 third edition " chapter 1.2.5. Permutations and factorials professor Knuth introduces method for constructing all permutation of $n$ objects from permutations of $n - 1$ objects. He introduces two methods. I am unable to understand how one of the methods works. Can you please help me out. Here is quotation from the book: 
 [image]

How do you exactly rename elements? What does he mean by preserving order. I can see that in the first permutation 2 becomes 1, 3 becomes 4, and 1 becomes 2. But in the second permutation 1 remains 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I guess the notation means that $a_{1} \dots a_{n-1}$ is the permutation taking $i$ to $a_{i}$.

Then, let us see what **preserving orders** means, for instance for the second permutation
$$\tag{orig}
2 3 1 \frac{3}{2},
$$
In it, the numbers
$$
2, 3, 1, \frac{3}{2}
$$
appear. Sort them in increasing order, as
$$\tag{sorted}
1, \frac{3}{2}, 2, 3.
$$
Now in (orig) replace

- $1$ by $1$ (as $1$ is the $1$-st number in (sorted)),
- $\dfrac{3}{2}$ by $2$ (as $\dfrac{3}{2}$ is the $2$-nd number in (sorted)),
- $2$ by $3$ (etc), and
- $3$ by $4$,

to get
$$
3 4 1 2.
$$

Comment: It does work!. Thank you for your answer. Do you think the method is explained clearly in the text? Were you able to understand the method right away after reading the quote?

Comment: You're welcome! Well, I understood it right away, but I've been in this business for several decades...